# Docker nginx proxy_pass - Upstream connection refused

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have launched a simple Docker container with Nginx, I want to use this Docker Nginx as a reverse proxy for my application (HTTP Tomcat) on my host. But my `proxy_pass` only works with an unexpected IP value.

**Expected behaviour:** When I use `docker inspect` on my container, my **Gateway** is `172.29.0.1`, my `proxy_pass` should work with `172.29.0.1`.

**Current:** I have to use `172.18.0.1` in my `proxy_pass` to make it work, and **I don't understand why this random value works**. If I don't use `172.18.0.1` then I have a 502 HTTP error, and my docker logs shows me "*Upstream connection refused*".

My *Dockerfile* (contains only 1 line):

`FROM nginx`

My *docker-compose* (I use the `docker-compse up --build` to launch my container):

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-web:
    image: nginx-web
    container_name: nginx-web-container
    build: .
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - ./volume-sources/nginx-conf-files:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

My *nginx file* (my `nginx-web` value is the **Gateway** value which is `172.29.0.1`, but it works when manually set it to `172.18.0.1`):

```
upstream upstream-nginx-web {
    server nginx-web:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-site.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://upstream-nginx-web;
    }
}
```

On my **host** `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.110.23.254 dev enp0s31f6 
10.110.20.0/22 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 10.110.20.76 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6 scope link metric 1000
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.29.0.0/16 dev br-56b3c9a632cf proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.101 metric 600
```

**Another *weird* behaviour:**

I have restart my container with `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --always-recreate-deps`, but this time my **Gateway** is `172.17.0.1` but the reverse proxy only works if `proxy_pass` use this IP: `172.19.0.1`.

Notes:

- My Docker version: 18.06.1-ce
- My docker-compose version: 1.22.0
- My OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- I don't use PHP on my host, I have a Tomcat server listening port number 8000.
- `host.docker.internal` and `gateway.host.internal` are only available under Windows and Mac, that's why I use the `nginx-web` (in my Nginx file) which is the Gateway value automatically set by *docker-compose*.

Questions:

1. Where is my mistake?
2. What do I have to change to make it work and why?

Thanks

Comment: Docker Compose will automatically create a Docker-private network for each deployment, and I bet that’s why you’re not seeing the default bridge IP.  Will one of your other host IP addresses work (maybe 10.110.20.76)?

Comment: Yes, your solution with `10.110.20.76` works, but I will not use it. Your answer helped me to find the solution in another way: Make **docker-compose** use the default Docker network (*docker0*) in order to fix the Gateway IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**docker-compose** automatically create a new network at each deployment.
It's possible to **fix the Gateway IP address** by using the `network_mode: bridge` option in your **docker-compose** file. With this solution you will use Docker's default network (*docker0*).

If you use the `network_mode: bridge` option, you won't be able to use your Docker service name in the `upstream` like I did in my original example:

```
upstream upstream-nginx-web {
  # "nginx-web" is NOT recognized if "network_mode: bridge"
  server nginx-web:8000;

  # Use your Docker Gateway (which can be 172.17.0.1)
  server 172.17.0.1:8000;
}
```

You can find your Docker Gateway with the following docker command:

```
docker network inspect bridge --format="{{ (index .IPAM.Config 0).Gateway }}"
```

Result:

```
172.17.0.1
```

Comment: you ve just save my life